# setup wizard silent argument

Tags: silent-installer, setup-wizard

I have a solution that contains a setup project(made with VS2008 setup wizard). I need to have the option to silently install the setup project. I read that in order to do this, I should delete the User Interface screens. But this will make my setup project ONLY silent. I need it to be available to be used normally (non-silent), and when called with a specific argument, to be silent.

So my  2 questions:

- How can I pass arguments to the setup project?
- How can I create a silent install procedure, while also keeping the normal setup, when the project is  called with no argument?

If there are resources on the web, please point me to them.

Comment: Is it a msi or an exe? These all take standard options to run in silent mode with switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup exe can usually be run in silent mode using:

```
setup.exe /q
```

MSI can be run in silent mode using:

```
msiexec /qn /i setup.msi
```

Comment: Thank you but I just tried to test this from the command line and it does not work. When I run this, it pops the msiexec argument list. Should I modify something in the installer?

Comment: I think /i needs to come before the setup.msi, try that.

Comment: This almost worked. But when using a log argument to see what happens, I get: "Error 1303. The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\[ProductName]".